# Office - Fully maximized is not 100% of height

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-office

My Office 2013 applications (Word, Excel and Outlook) are maximized, but somehow there is a gap of like 1 or 2 pixels above the minimize, maximize and close buttons. When I try to minimize an Office application, I move my cursor to the top of my screen thinking I will hit the minimize icon, but I hit the minimize button of the application behind. Quite annoying.

[image: Office 2013 can't fully maximize]

Is there a way I can fix this? Thank you!

- Office 2013 x64 (French)
- Windows 7 Enterprise x64 (French)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possibilities that I can think of:

Office applications window placement data is incorrect. (or)
An application has docked itself in the upper region.

For case 1, the problem may be fixed by changing the screen resolution, maximizing the Office apps, and then reverting back to the original resolution.

Credits:
[microsoft office - Word does not maximize to full screen - Super User :](https://superuser.com/questions/93258/word-does-not-maximize-to-full-screen)